# Optional generic parameters in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

Here's the current problem I'm trying to solve, we have the following interface in Kotlin:

```
interface Parent<out Result, in Params> where Result : Any {
    fun run(params: Params): Result
}
```

The issue here is that sometimes I don't want to pass any params to the interface so I end up passing Unit as the type parameter and the overriding class ends up looking like this:

```
class Child : Parent<String, Unit> {
    override fun run(params: Unit): String { ... }
}
```

End Goal: It would be nice to add some abstraction in order to "get" a `run` function with no Params at all when `Params` is `Unit`
like:

```
class Child : Parent<SomeEntity, Unit> {
    override fun run(): Entity { ... }
}
```

Or even better, optionally pass the second type parameter in order to have a single class that take one or two type parameters.

```
class Child : Parent<String> {
    override fun run(): Entity { ... }
}
```

Same Parent class with params

```
class Child : Parent<String, Int> {
    override fun run(params: Int): String { ... }
}
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: I think you changed a type name in your example interface and missed updating it. "Entity" doesn't match "Result" or "Params".

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what i did haha

Answer (score 3):

You can create an extension function that handles `Parent`s where the second type is a Unit. The function will only be available for use when the second type is a match for Unit:

```
fun <Result> Parent<Result, Unit>.run() = run(Unit)
```

The terminology you're using is atypical. A class that implements an interface is not a child of that interface. It is a child of whatever its superclass is.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do anything special with a single interface. ‍♂️
The one solution that comes to mind is creating a child interface with a single type parameter that overrides the `Unit` function delegating to a different one without parameters.
Something like:

```
interface Parent1<out Result> : Parent<Result, Unit> {
    override fun run(params: Unit): Result = run()
    fun run(): Result
}
```